# Asynchronous communication and socket creating

Tags: java, sockets, networking

This image is desrcibed as follow:
[image]

> ‒ request, response each has socket, client and server define
>   endpoints    ‒ |treq – tres | can be large (hours, even days)
>
> ‒ harder to do across network elements (private/public networks issue)

However, when are two sockets created? Are both sockets created on the first "create order" request? If yes then why do we need 2 sockets, and not 1 when we can keep it open?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: They're created when used. It would not be async if the the socket was 2-way. The socket can only handle 1 thread at a time, so if the socket is trying to send 'order created' response, then it would block 'create order' requests from going through.

Comment: But how does server know what client it should connect to (create the socket with) ? Does it store information about the first socket? Does client listen to the port for handshake?

Comment: That is too broad of a question -- you're getting into system requirements. Either the response socket information is provided with the original request or the system is hardcoded to send responses to a particular socket. Which one is used depends on your requirements.